# Simulation of cursor based UI using JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane, flowlayout

I'm trying to make a Kinect driven UI using JLayeredPane. UI consists of 4 JPanels. On the top of these 4 JPanels, I'd like to paint a cursor to show user's cursor. When using JLayeredPane, I'm not able to get the cursor moving. The cursor should be drawn on top of these 4 JPanels, so that I put the JPanel, which paints the cursor in the higher layer. My code looks like this:

```
    mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    mainFrame.setTitle("Kinect module"); 
    mainFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1180, 110));
    Color controlPanelBcg = new Color(255, 64, 16);
    controlPanel.setBackground(controlPanelBcg);

    propertiesPanel = new JPanel();
    propertiesPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(210, 540));
    Color propertiesPanelBcg = new Color(16, 255, 64);
    propertiesPanel.setBackground(propertiesPanelBcg);

    statusPanel = new JPanel();
    statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1180, 110));
    Color statusPanelBcg = new Color(64, 16, 255);
    statusPanel.setBackground(statusPanelBcg);
    statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1180, 110));

    displayPanel = displayManager.getJPanel(DisplayType.DEFAULT);
    displayPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(960, 540));

    cursorPanel = new CursorPanel(context, sessMan);
    cursorPanel.setVisible(true);
    cursorPanel.setSize(1200, 800);
    cursorPanel.setOpaque(false);

    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 820));
    layeredPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));
    layeredPane.add(controlPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    layeredPane.add(displayPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    layeredPane.add(propertiesPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    layeredPane.add(statusPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    layeredPane.add(cursorPanel, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER);

    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
    mainFrame.pack();
```

The layout is made just like I want it to be. But when I want to paint a cursor in cursorPanel's method paintComponent(Graphics g) - nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Posting a graphic would help.

Comment: For overlaying the cursor jpanel over the rest you would have to use the [`Overlay Layout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html) manager instead of `Flowlayout`for the layeredpane